# java - end loop when user types "N"

Tags: java

When the user selects yes, it loops and starts again. When the user selects N, it should end the program but I am not sure what I am missing here. This is a program to tell you the x and y values when giving the slope and y-intercept to the program.

**Java file**

```
        int slope;
        int yintercept;
        String newEquation;
        boolean play = true; 


        System.out.print("Enter the slope: ");
        slope = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter y-intercept: ");
        yintercept = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("The equation of the line is: y = %dx + %d", slope, yintercept);

        System.out.print("\nWould you like to create a new equation... Y or N? ");
        newEquation = input.next();


            while (play)
            {
                if (newEquation.equals("Y"))
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter the slope: ");
                    slope = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("Enter y-intercept: ");
                    yintercept = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.printf("The equation of the line is: y = %dx + %d", slope, yintercept);

                    System.out.print("\nWould you like to create a new equation... Y or N? ");
                    newEquation = input.next();
                }
                if (newEquation.equals("N")){
                    play =false; 

                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("Enter the slope: ");
                    slope = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("Enter y-intercept: ");
                    yintercept = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.printf("The equation of the line is: y = %dx + %d", slope, yintercept);

                    System.out.print("\nWould you like to create a new equation... Y or N? ");
                    newEquation = input.next();
                }





            }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It works for me.  Are you typing "n" instead of "N"?

Comment: You could greatly simplify your code by using the do-while construct of Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: oh wow how stupid am i

Comment: "When the user selects yes, it loops and starts again" I doubt that. You never check for "yes"

Comment: @FredK There's enough repetition that it actually does repeat if they type "yes".  It just goes into the "else" instead of the first "if".

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the same code in  **if (newEquation.equals("Y"))** and **else** part? If you expect user only to enter "Y" or "N", then you can  put else in fron, like this:
`else if(newEquation.equals("N"))`
and delete **else**  part.

Because the way how you wrote it, it tests if input is "Y", and then second time in the same loop iteration it is going to test if input is "N", so that means that your program take the slope info twice once when it goes trough loop, because else refers only to "N".

Answer (score 0):

Try a do-while construct, as well as a `equalsIgnoreCase` (to make "y" and "Y" both tested against "Y").

```
int slope;
int yintercept;
String newEquation;
boolean play = true; 


do
{
    System.out.print("Enter the slope: ");
    slope = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter y-intercept: ");
    yintercept = input.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("The equation of the line is: y = %dx + %d", slope, yintercept);

    System.out.print("\nWould you like to create a new equation... Y or N? ");
    newEquation = input.next();
} while newEquation.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
```

(I have only cut-and-pasted your lines, but have not compiled and tested. My apologies if I missed something.)

The do-while tests if the user has typed a Y/y after the first round. Note that the user doesn't have to type N/n, but instead could type, say, q in order for the loop to terminate.